# Failed "import matplotlib.pylab" due to /backends/_macosx.so Reason: image not found

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, matplotlib

#### System and software versions:

- OSX 10.7.4
- matplotlib 1.1.1 for Python 2.7 and OSX 10.6, installed via .mpkg.
- Python 2.7.3, installed via .mpkg.

  > > > import matplotlib.pylabTraceback (most recent call last):
  > > >       File "", line 1, in 
  > > >       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7.egg/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 265, in 
  > > >       from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  > > >       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 97, in 
  > > >       new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  > > >       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7.egg/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
  > > >       globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  > > >       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 21, in 
  > > >       from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
  > > >       ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so, 2): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
  > > >       Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.x-py2.7.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so
  > > >       Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

also see:

http://www.zqna.net/qna/knuzvt-i-am-getting-this-error-on-using-matplotlib.html

My solution:

I have OS X 10.7.5, running python 2.7.1, numpy-1.8.0.dev_4600b2f_20130131-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg, scipy-0.12.0.dev_b69fe18_20130131-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg

Previously I got the error you have listed above with matplotlib 1.3 not being able to find the CoreText.framework, but when i reverted to matplotlib 1.2 the error went away and i was able to run it just fine - I just edited the easy_install.pth file (not sure if this is the right way to manage the problem, but then I didn't need to make a symlink because the old 1.2 version worked just fine)

The easy install was a reinstall from the fonnesbeck scipy superpack on Feb 8, 2013, I was trying to get everything new since last fall.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
brew install pkg-config
brew link pkg-config
brew install pygtk
brew install freetype
brew install libpng

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/*/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc

git clone git@github.com:matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

References:

http://blog.caoyuan.me/2012/08/matplotlib-error-mac-os-x/
http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#install-from-git
http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~dtsang/python.html